# carrying a form value into another webpage using PHP

Tags: php, sql, forms, pdo

I know asp can carry over the form value and plug it into another linked page. Is there a way to do this with PHP PDO script. For example, I have a new table entry on my mock site for each  new member. For each record a form button called "member profile" is created that has the value of the member in that same row. When I click the button I want the member name to carry to a new page and link to that phpmyadmin table and display all of the date for that member. I hope I explained that right. and here is my code

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=averyit_net';
$db_username = "root";
$db_password = "password";


$db = new PDO ($dsn, $db_username, $db_password);

$tablemaker = $db->query("SELECT `cust_profile`.`CustomerName`,                 
`cust_profile`.`CustomerType`, `cust_profile`.`ContractHours` FROM `cust_profile` ORDER       
BY    `CustomerName`");
while ($rows = $tablemaker->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

?>
<table width="75%"  border="1" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<th width="15%" height="0%" bgcolor="#819FF7"> </th>
<th width="35%" height="0%" bgcolor="#819FF7"> </th>
<th width="30%" height="0%" bgcolor="#819FF7"> </th>
<th width="20%" height="0%" bgcolor="#819FF7"> </th>
<tr> 

<form method="post" action="edit_cust.php" >
  <td align="center"> 
    <span style="font-size: 9pt"><font size="1" face="Verdana">
        <input TYPE="submit" NAME="dothis0" value="Customer Profile">      
</font></span><font face="Verdana"><font size="2">
    </font>
    <input type="hidden" name="custID" value="<?php echo $rows['CustomerName']; ?>">
    </font>
  </td>
</form>
```

Comment: AND YES, i know about using the <font> tags...

Comment: change the method="post" to "get"

Comment: but then how does the new page that opens know where to put that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you change you form `method="get"`

submitted the form will redirect you to your `action="edit_cust.php"`

that will produce a url that contains a parameter of your `CustomerName` like this

*www.localhost/website/edit_cust.php?name=Me*

then you can get or use that data on edit_cust.php by using $_GET[] global variabel

```
// set it to variable..
$CustomerName = $_GET['name'];
//note: your $_GET[] parameter should equal to what is in your url to gets its value...
```

then your customer name can be ready to used using the variable `$customerName`

Answer (score 0):

```
change method="post" to method="get"

on your second form you will be posted a url like this (ie):

script.php?your_variable=lorem&second_variable=ipsum

<input type="text" value="<?=($_GET['your_variable']) ? htmlentities($_GET['your_variable']) : ''?>" name="field_name">

<input type="text" value="<?=($_GET['second_variable']) ? htmlentities($_GET['second_variable']) : ''?>" name="field_name">
```

Comment: ok, so if I just want the CustomerName to transfer to the new page I would do something like script.php?CustomerName=loram                      <input type="text" value=<?=($_GET(['CustomerName']) ? htmlentities($_GET(['CustomerName']) : ''?>" name = "Customer Name">

Comment: <input type="text" value="<?=($_GET['CustomerName']) ? $_GET['CustomerName'] : "" ?>" name="CustomerName">

Comment: what is the "lorem" pointing to that I should replace it with? I hope that's not a dumb question

Comment: lorem is just a dummy value. In your first form, if someone types in foobar as their name.. it would redirect you to script.php?customerName=foobar